# Are there special names for lower dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-numbers

For $n$-dimensional real number set $\mathbb{R}^n$, its $n-1$ dimensional subspaces are called hyperplanes.  Are there special names for lower dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: "Subspace of dimension $k$" (where $k \leq n$) is quite specific.

Comment: I have heard the term "hyperplane" refer to any $m$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ for $m<n$. I'd go with avs's suggestion though.

Comment: I seem to recall *$k$-flats* referring to $k$-dimensional (affine) subspaces, but evidently it's less common than I'd thought.

Comment: @Wojowu I used to think that way, too.  But I recently read that hyperplane was only for n-1 subspace.  Thus the question.

Answer (score 2):

An $n-k$ dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is often called a **codimension $k$** subspace. I don't believe a more general term exists.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you already know that :

- A subspace of dimension $1$ is called a *line*.
- A subspace of dimension $2$ is called a *plane*.
- A subspace of codimension $1$ is called an *hyperplane* (as you stated).